# Can't opt out of Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview, downgrade, windows-insider

I switched off the Insider Preview about 2 months ago, but I am still getting a message on my desktop that I am running Build 18272.re_prerelease.181026-1425.

How do I revert back to a more stable release as this release seems to have a few issues at the moment.

I keep getting the following message when I login.  At the end of December 2018, I tried switching to a different release and I saw no way of doing that.

[image]

Comment: You cannot opt out of Insider Preview using the build you are on.  You failed to change your release branch before you migrated to the RS5 (1903) branch.  You will have to wait until RS5 (1903) is released to switch your release branch at that time.[18272](https://changewindows.org/build/18272) was released back in October 2018. So the fact you changed 2 months ago means, you changed the branch 4 months after 1809 was released.

Comment: @Ramhound, can he download the latest *release* ISO and install to regress?

Comment: @Ramhound, But I keep getting a message when I boot that I will be able to opt out of the Insider Preview on December 2018 or something like that.  That month came and went..  I'll post a screenshot of the message the next time I see it.

Comment: You likely will have to do an in-place upgrade of the current RS5 ISO.  I assume you are offered no cumulative Windows Updates?

Comment: @Ramhound, Correct, I am not getting any updates at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I revert back to a more stable release as this release seems to have a few issues at the moment.

You cannot downgrade to 1809.

> At the end of December 2018, I tried switching to a different release and I saw no way of doing that.

You missed your chance to do this back in October 2018.  You will have to wait until 1903 is released to move back to the Semi-Annual Targeted or Semi-Annual release branch.

You only have choices to move forward.  Your first choice, at the moment, is to download the current RS5 Insider Preview ISO, provided it's a build that is greater than the one you currently have installed.  Your second choice is to remain on the build your currently using, and manually upgrade to 1903 once it's released.

It's very likely based on the fact you have not received a single Windows Update in 6 months, Windows Update has been broken for a while.